# Использование вначале переменных при вызове программы

Tags: python, bash

Не знаю переменные ли это или нет, но что это такое и как прочитать их в программе?

```
$ FOO=1 BAR=2 python3 ./make.py
```

Что за `FOO` и `BAR`?

P.S. Python

Comment: `python3 --help`

Comment: @IgorSergeevich и?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> $ FOO=1 BAR=2 python3 ./make.py
> ```

такой синтаксис используется в *posix*-совместимых оболочках для присвоения значений переменным окружения.

обратиться к переменным окружения внутри скрипта, написанного на *python*, [можно с помощью `os.environ`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4906977/4827341):

```
import os
print os.environ['FOO']
print os.environ['BAR']
```

Answer (score 1):

Команда `python --help` выводит `usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...` попробуйте аргументы добавить после файла

```
python3 ./make.py FOO=1 BAR=2
```

Посмотрите сам скрипт, там есть парсинг аргументов? Выложите код `make.py` например [сюда](https://pastebin.com) можно будет посмотреть есть ли там аргументы и как они названы

Comment: я имел ввиду вначале вызова или нет разницы?